# If time travel possible then we able to travel to future or past

Tags: time, time-travel

If time travel possible?
If we can travel in future?
If we can travel in past? Or Both actually?

Comment: If traveling to the past is possible, then it already has happened, because the 4-dimensional spacetime is static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only into the future. Just wait a second and you are there. Not what you meant, I know. But that is all that is possible.

There are some iffy scenarios involving rotating black holes or worm holes. But nothing we can do.